# Measurement in many body systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Any wavefunction for a system of many particles can be decomposed into linear combinations of the direct product of single particle states with respect to a certain observable(single particle basis).

Is it possible to measure an observable for one of the particles in a system(instead of the whole?).If so, how would the total wavefunction collapse upon the measurement? Sources elucidating the mathematics would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all, let's clarify things:**

In Quantum Mechanics decomposing the wavefunction into a linear combination of eigenstates is not the same as decomposing the system into single particle basis.

Say you have a unidimensional system of two particles, the wavefunction in terms of their position is $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ can be decomposed into a linear combination of eigenstates:

$$\psi(x_1,x_2) = \sum{c_k\psi_k(x_1,x_2)}$$

This is different to stating that the wavefunction can be expressed as independent a product of independent single-particle wavefunctions:

$$\psi(x_1,x_2) = \psi_1(x_1)\psi_2(x_2)$$

The former is always possible, the latter not always.

**Now to your question:**

Rigorously speaking, no, you cannot measure an observable of one of the particles composing the system without affecting the others, at least in real systems, since all of them interact.

In an atom, the electrons interact with each other and change in the state of one of them should affect the others.

**However**, if the interactions are sufficiently weak, this is possible. Think of exciting the outermost electron of a Lithium atom: it interacts very weakly with the electrons of the lower shell which are paired and strongly coupled to each other. That is why you can write the wavefunction of the system as the product of the outer electron's and that of the rest of the system.

This means also, that a change of the wavefunction of the outer electron will not change the superposition state of the rest of the system due to their weak coupling. In mathematical terms, the wavefunctions are independent hence the Hamiltonian is separable and partial Hamiltonians (and all operators related each of the system) will commute.

### Further Analysis from comments

For the sake of clarity, let's build the wavefunction of a simple system using a single-particle basis as stated in your reference. This will demonstrate how there is no contradiction between the stated above and the method in the reference.

Let's consider a two particle system (1 and 2), and whose variables will have their indexes like $x_1, x_2$ or $p_1,p_2$. Further, let's assume that we have a complete single-particle basis which consists only of 3 eigenfunctions $\phi_a,\phi_b,\phi_c$.

Now we will express the total wavefunction of the system $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ in the way according to your reference. The coefficients would be:

$$A_{a1}(x_2) = \int \phi^*_a(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1$$
$$A_{b1}(x_2) = \int \phi^*_b(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1$$
$$A_{c1}(x_2) = \int \phi^*_c(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1$$

then multiplying each equation by the corresponding eigenfunction (evaluated on the particle 1 variable $\bar x_1$) and summing these equations we get on the left side:

$$A_{a1}(x_2)\phi_{a}(\bar x_1)+A_{b1}(x_2)\phi_{b}(\bar x_1)+A_{c1}(x_2)\phi_{c}(\bar x_1)$$

and on the right side

$$\int \left( \phi_a(\bar x_1)\phi^*_a(x_1)+\phi_b(\bar x_1)\phi^*_b(x_1)+\phi_c(\bar x_1)\phi^*_c(x_1)\right)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1=\int \delta(x_1-\bar x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2)dx_1=\psi(\bar x_1,x_2)$$

Subsequently we perform the same operation for the next particle, to find the constant coefficients:

$$A_{a1,a2} = \int \int \phi^*_a(x_2)\phi^*_a(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$
$$A_{a1,b2} = \int \int \phi^*_b(x_2)\phi^*_a(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$
$$A_{a1,c2} = \int \int \phi^*_c(x_2)\phi^*_a(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$

$$A_{b1,a2} = \int \int \phi^*_a(x_2)\phi^*_b(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$
$$A_{b1,b2} = \int \int \phi^*_b(x_2)\phi^*_b(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$
$$A_{b1,c2} = \int \int \phi^*_c(x_2)\phi^*_b(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$

$$A_{c1,a2} = \int \int \phi^*_a(x_2)\phi^*_c(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$
$$A_{c1,b2} = \int \int \phi^*_b(x_2)\phi^*_c(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$
$$A_{c1,c2} = \int \int \phi^*_c(x_2)\phi^*_c(x_1)\psi(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$

Which finally, performing a similar operation of multiplying by the appropriate pair of functions $\phi_\alpha(\bar x_1)\phi_\beta(\bar x_2)$ and summing doubly, will yield:

$$\psi(x_1, x_2) = A_{a1,a2}\phi_a(x_1)\phi_a(x_2)+A_{a1,b2}\phi_a(x_1)\phi_b(x_2)+A_{a1,c2}\phi_a(x_1)\phi_c(x_2)+A_{b1,a2}\phi_b(x_1)\phi_a(x_2)+A_{b1,b2}\phi_b(x_1)\phi_b(x_2)+A_{b1,c2}\phi_b(x_1)\phi_c(x_2)+A_{c1,a2}\phi_c(x_1)\phi_a(x_2)+A_{c1,b2}\phi_c(x_1)\phi_b(x_2)+A_{c1,c2}\phi_c(x_1)\phi_c(x_2)$$

The above expression is clear, it is saying *"the total wave function of the system is expressible in **all possible** product-combinations of the single particle basis"*. But it does not imply any particle is in any fixed state. Let's show this explicitly; putting the expression in the form:

$$\psi(x_1, x_2) = A_{a1,a2}\psi_{a1,a2}+A_{a1,b2}\psi_{a1,b2}+A_{a1,c2}\psi_{a1,c2}+A_{b1,a2}\psi_{b1,a2}+A_{b1,b2}\psi_{b1,b2}+A_{b1,c2}\psi_{b1,c2}+A_{c1,a2}\psi_{c1,a2}+A_{c1,b2}\psi_{c1,b2}+A_{c1,c2}\psi_{c1,c2} $$

it looks as a linear combination of some total states in which the particles are in fixed single-states.

Now let's consider your enquiry, what happens to the expression above if we manage to assert that particle 1 is in state $\phi_b$? Meaning measuring it and finding it occupies the b state, or making the collapse of the total wavefunction such that particle one is in the mentioned state. Well obviously the total function will not have collapsed to any of the terms in the above expression where particle 1 is not in the mentioned state. Meaning the expression is reduced to:

$$\psi(x_1, x_2) = A_{b1,a2}\psi_{b1,a2}+A_{b1,b2}\psi_{b1,b2}+A_{b1,c2}\psi_{b1,c2}$$

And in this expression can be seen that particle 2 is not necessarily in a fixed state, it could be in a combination of states. In effect, if we rewrite the expression as above and factorize the particle 1 eigenfunction:

$$\psi(x_1, x_2) = \phi_b(x_1) \left[A_{b1,a2}\phi_a(x_2)+A_{b1,b2}\phi_b(x_2)+A_{b1,c2}\phi_c(x_2)\right] = \phi_b(x_1)\phi(x_2)$$

which clearly a product of a wavefunction of particle 1 (in state b) by the wavefunction for particle 2 (in some mixed state).

So when you "measure" particle 1, it does not make, in general, particle 2 collapse to a specific single-particle state. Furthermore the probability of finding particle 2 in a certain state depends on which state particle 1 collapsed to, since the constants are different $A_{b1,a1} \ne A_{c1,a1}$, and this can be proven to be directly related to the potential operator. And finally, the order of measuring the particles will affect the probabilities too.

A special case is when the particles do not interact at all, in which case their probabilities are independent and whatever order chosen, the same values will be found.

In summary, as stated above, one of the particles of the system can be measured (ex. hydrogen-like atoms electron excitation), but its effect on the rest of the system depends on the actual case (might make the whole system collapse or some parts due to the interaction between components). How does the total wave function collapse? Again, depends on the system, it can be answered by theoretical calculation of the coefficients above, or by measuring repeatedly in different combinations, each of the particles and finding the frequencies of occurrence of different results.

Comment: Say, there is the wavefunction for two particles $\Ket{\psi (x_1,x_2)} = \sum_{k,j} p_{k,j} \Ket{\phi _k (x_1)}\Ket{\phi_j(x_2)$, since it is always possible to decompose a multi-particle wavefunction into a linear combination of the 'direct product' of single particle eigenstates. Here the decomposition is in the same observable basis for both the particles.
Now, if we measure the observable for particle 1 and we get an eigenvalue r, corresponding to $\ket{\phi _r (x_1)}$, what would be the wavefunction for the second particle now?

Comment: The answer is: the same wavefunction, it will be unchanged. But I must insist, this is because you are assuming a priori the independence between the particles, i.e. no interaction between them in any form. Your assumption is implicit in the fact that you express your eigenfunctions as products of single-particle function. And this, I must insist, is not always possible. If the particles interact, there is not the possibility of splitting into a product. The wavefunction has to comply with $\hat H \psi(x_1,x_2)=ih\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x_1,x_2)$ which does not  restrict$\psi(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: I am not talking about the 'eigenfunctions' of the two particle Hamiltonian or any other two-particle operator. The individual $\phi$ are eigenfuctions of some one-particle observable. And any multi-particle wavefunction can be broke up into linear combinations of the product of these functions. However, as you said in your answer, it might not be possible to 'factorize' the wavefunction in case of interacting particles, which is not what I am ssuming here. I am breaking up the wfunction ito 'linear combinations', not assuming that it is factorizable. And that is always possible.

Comment: If you have a reference proving that "any multi-particle wavefunction can be broke up into linear combinations of the product of these functions" I would like to read it, because I don't know of any. What I have seen is that in general, the Hilbert space for a generic two-body state cannot be exhausted by a base made of one-particle-states-product. It is not a complete base unless some constraints are imposed.

Comment: http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~jarrell/COURSES/ADV_SOLID_HTML/Other_online_texts/Many-body%20quantum%20theory%20in%0Acondensed%20matter%20physics%0AHenrik%20Bruus%20and%20Karsten%20Flensberg.pdf

Page 6, Equation (1.21). The proof is there too.

Comment: I see now where the problem is. I will add in my answer a complete analysis to answer your question.

Comment: Have you found anything?

Comment: Yes, I added an analysis of the cited reference. Please add the reference to your question, since I think is fundamental  in understanding what was the origin of your question.

Comment: You should edit your answer! It still begins with the wrong and somewhat illogical statement that $\psi$ cannot be represented by $\psi(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} \phi_i(x_1) \phi_j(x_2)$

Answer (score 1):

Take for example the two particle wave function
$$|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle_1 \otimes |1\rangle_2 + |1\rangle_1 \otimes |0\rangle_2\right)$$
The probability to measure 0 for the first particle is given by
$$
|\langle 0_1|\text{Tr}_2(|\Psi\rangle)|^2 = \frac{1}{2} 
$$
The wave function after the collapse if 0 was measured is
$$
|\Psi_c\rangle = \sqrt{2}\langle 0_1|\Psi\rangle |0\rangle_1 = |0\rangle_1 \otimes |1\rangle_2
$$